# Is there a tool or method to list signals that have no reset in the HDL design for an FPGA?

Tags: fpga, reset, vivado, quartus, verification

I have to reuse an old VHDL draft design which was not fully verified and validated.

The code is huge - it takes around 30k slices to be implemented on an FPGA. I see that some signals are forgotten to be reset.

Is there a way to list all non-reset signals with a tool like Vivado or Quartus, or maybe a method?

Comment: Well, in the simulation you will get "Unknown" value for these before they are assigned.

Comment: I tried to review all them in simulation. Some of them are initialized, thus not undefined

Comment: You mean initialized as in `initial` block or some other non-synthesizable way?

Comment: I mean something like this in vhdl: signal counter : unsigned(7 downto 0) := "00000000";

Comment: Yea, a linter. But may not be getting a free tool if VHDL.

Comment: @Mitu Raj do you have any to recommand?

Comment: There are tools like Questa Autocheck, but they are licensed for industrial use. If Verilog, you could have used open-source tools like Verilator Lint.

Comment: You can consider writing a perl or python script which parses your VHDL file and find out the signals which are not reset. For eg: Filter out all signals which have been declared inside `architecture`, then filter out the signals which are not assigned inside `if(reset)` block. This would have been simpler job if all the clocked signals have a specific naming convention like 'xx_reg'.

Comment: @Mitu Raj, my answer below. Did you know this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to list all forgotten resets of a design or module. This is possible with the tool called Synplify Pro.

The tool is not free in its standalone version I guess. But it is possible to use it in a free version through Lattice Diamond tool. Lattice Diamond tool uses Synplify Pro for synthesis. It is included in the install. The license is free (to download on Lattice website)

I created a project for my module with Lattice Diamond tool and opened the .srr file generated after synthesis and found the following warning:

> @A: CL282 :"C:\test\test\vhdl\counter.vhd":40:4:40:5|Feedback mux created for signal busy. It is possible a set/reset assignment for this is signal missing. To improve timing and area, specify a set/reset value.

This is a single line for one signal, there are much more in my srr file.

My resets are asynchronous ones.